# Error response from daemon: Container nova-ca6efe81-f1 is not running

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I am trying to run docker container on bluemix

> docker version on my local sys is  Docker version 1.11.2, build
>   b9f10c9 ibm-container plugin version IBM-Containers   0.8.897   ic
>   IBM Containers plug-in cf --version cf version
>   6.21.0+dff2cf8-2016-07-27

This is my simple hello world docker file

```
FROM ubuntu RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get install -y wget vim RUN
apt-get install -y python
RUN mkdir /local 
ADD hello.py
/local/hello.py WORKDIR /local
```

I have built this and pushed to ibm bluemix image registry
to run the docker container:

```
cf ic run --name=testnode registry.ng.bluemix.net/manikkandanb/cardcamp
```

next

```
cf ic exec testnode date
```

> Error response from daemon: Container
>   nova-ca6efe81-f1d6-4939-be21-d40f1a702aee is not running FAILED
>   Command failed

```
cf ic exec testnode python /local/hello.py
```

> Error response from daemon: Container
>   nova-ca6efe81-f1d6-4939-be21-d40f1a702aee is not running FAILED
>   Command failed

what am I missing here? why cant I execute the script or any commands in this container?

NOTE: the same docker image works in any other environment but this bluemix.

Comment: what is the output of cf ic ps ?

Comment: web@web-virtual-machine:~$ cf ic exec testnode date,
`Error response from daemon: Container nova-02022e58-9699-4db1-a9ca-22ff74505583 is not running
FAILED
Command failed`

web@web-virtual-machine:~$ cf ic ps,
`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                  COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                  PORTS               NAMES`,
`02022e58-969        registry.ng.bluemix.net/manikkandanb/cardcamp:latest   ""                  4 minutes ago       Running 3 minutes ago                       testnode`

Answer (score 1):

The command cf ic ps -a might report that a container is running while it in real life is stopped

make sure that your container is running by adding a command that prevent the contriner for stopping.
This could be done by adding this line to the end of your Dockerfile
CMD tail -F -n0 /etc/hosts

....
if not you could try this Dockerfile:

`FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Rune Langoy "rune@something.com"
RUN apt-get update
CMD tail -F -n0 /etc/hosts`